# Reset dropdown to selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an index page that displays all trips in the database. At the top of the page is a filter with drop downs where you can select either category, region, or both to filter down the results.

When you select your choices and click 'show' the drop downs go back to the default option of 'All categories' and 'All regions'.

How can I can get the selected option to display in the drop down when I filter the results?

Here is my drop down menu:

```
.row
  = form_tag all_road_trips_path, id: 'filter-trips-form', method: :get do
  .select-intro
    Browse
  .select-wrapper.trip-categories
    = collection_select(:category, :id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "All categories")
  .select-intro
    trips for
  .select-wrapper
    = collection_select(:region, :id, Region.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "All regions")
  .select-button
    = submit_tag 'Show Trips', class: 'button square'
```

EDIT::

I tried adding the `selected` value and got an 'undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass' error. I thought this was due to the first value of my drop down being 'All categories' and not actually being an object in the db, thus lacking an id. Here is updated code and server output:

```
.row
  = form_tag all_road_trips_path, id: 'filter-trips-form', method: :get do
  .select-intro
    Browse
  .select-wrapper.trip-categories
    = collection_select(:category, :id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "All categories", :selected => params[:category][:id])
  .select-intro
    trips for
  .select-wrapper.trip-regions
    = collection_select(:region, :id, Region.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "All regions", :selected => params[:region][:id])
  .select-button
    = submit_tag 'Show Trips', class: 'button square'
```

And

```
Started GET "/road-trips/all" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-10 14:03:39 -0600
Processing by RoadTripsController#all as HTML
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  Rendered road_trips/_trip_filter.html.haml (4.7ms)
  Rendered road_trips/all.html.haml within layouts/application (5.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1

NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/road_trips/_trip_filter.html.haml:6:in `block in _app_views_road_trips__trip_filter_html_haml__2571960046883419269_70320079055780'
  haml (3.1.8) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:162:in `block (2 levels) in form_tag_with_haml'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:selected` option:

```
= collection_select(:category, :id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "All categories", :selected => params[:category_id or however you store this value])
```

Discussed briefly in the bottom comment here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

What's going on: by passing in a value to the `:selected` option of the `collection_select` form helper, you're telling it to mark one of the option tags as selected when the values match. So for example given the options 'apple', 'banana', 'chocolate':

```
<select name="treat">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
</select>
```

When you pass in 'chocolate' to the `collection_select` form helper, it will match the value to the values of the option tags and mark the matched one as selected:

```
= collection_select :treat, args..., :selected => 'chocolate'
# will render:
<select name="treat">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="chocolate" selected>Chocolate</option>
</select>
```

Hope that helps.

**Edit:**
You are calling the params value incorrectly, instead of:

```
params[:category][:id]
```

it should be:

```
params[:category_id]
```

and that goes for the other param as well.

This is because the form helper: `collection_select :category, :id` will generate a select tag with the name `category_id` and that will be the param that is submitted.

The error `no method [] for nilClass` was being caused by `params[:category]` returning nil because there is no such param.

Comment: Great explanation. The only issue with this is that the first prompt, 'All categories' or 'All regions' is not a category or region in the database, so it doesn't have an id. Therefore when I try and load the page I get an 'undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass'. But if a selection has already been made then it loads fine and works as you explained. Thank you.

Comment: That's not what's causing that error. :prompt and :selected work well together even one of the prompt option has no value. If you want you can post the view code that's causing that as well as the error and first few lines of the backtrace

Comment: That fixed the nomethod error, but now the option picked on the drop down menu fails to be the selected item on reload. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: You can try inspecting the value of params[:category_id] and then cross check that with your rendered HTML select tag to make sure it's one of the option tag values

Comment: When I use params[:category_id] selected="selected" isn't even found in the html when I select an option. It is however present when I use params[:category][:id], then it just doesn't work on the initial page load when nothing is selected.

Comment: Not sure what your params look like, but sounds like they :id is indeed nested within :category, which means that when there is no search there will be no :category param. You can work around that by using try: params[:category].try(:[], :id) that should work for both cases.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I tried 'try' earlier but my syntax was wrong. Thanks for the lesson!